# SQL select case statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, case

i am using SQL Server 2008 R2
i have the store procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Code_Tourne_Matin
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@The_FA int,
@The_Jour int,
@The_Insee varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
declare @TheCode varchar(250)


set @TheCode = case
    when exists (SELECT T_TOURNE_LABEL.LIBELLE 
                  FROM TOURNE
                  LEFT JOIN T_TOURNE_LABEL ON TOURNE.LIB_TOURNE = T_TOURNE_LABEL.NOID
                  WHERE THE_FA = @The_FA AND 
                        NO_INSEE = @The_Insee AND 
                        JOUR = @The_Jour AND 
                       (datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 13 and 23 or datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 0 and 6)) then LIBELLE
    when exists (SELECT LIBELLE
                  FROM TOURNE
                  LEFT JOIN T_TOURNE_LABEL ON TOURNE.LIB_TOURNE = T_TOURNE_LABEL.NOID
                  WHERE THE_FA = @The_FA AND 
                        NO_INSEE = @The_Insee AND 
                        JOUR = 0 AND 
                       (datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 13 and 23 or datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 0 and 6)) then LIBELLE
    else '00'


    end


RETURN @TheCode  
END
```

i just want to return the libelle.
the first select with 3 variable when it found then retrun the libelle
else if run select with 2 variable when it found then retrun the libelle 
else retrun '00'

it seems syntax error on LIBELLE

any idea ?

Comment: Libelle exists only inside the () brackets but you're trying to access it outside of them.

Comment: If there's a row which matches the top select (with `JOUR = @The_Jour`), could there also be a row with `JOUR = 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like:

```
set @TheCode = COALESCE(
(SELECT TOP 1 T_TOURNE_LABEL.LIBELLE 
                  FROM TOURNE
                  LEFT JOIN T_TOURNE_LABEL ON TOURNE.LIB_TOURNE = T_TOURNE_LABEL.NOID
                  WHERE THE_FA = @The_FA AND 
                        NO_INSEE = @The_Insee AND 
                        (JOUR = @The_Jour OR JOUR = 0) AND 
                       (datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 13 and 23 or datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 0 and 6)
ORDER BY JOUR DESC), '00')
```

Should cover all of your cases. (If there can never be two matching rows from your query where one has `JOUR = @The_Jour` and the other has `JOUR = 0`, then you can remove the `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` clauses (note that I've assumed that any possible `@The_Jour` value is > 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
set @TheCode =(  SELECT   ISNULL(( SELECT TOP 1 T_TOURNE_LABEL.LIBELLE
               FROM   TOURNE
               LEFT JOIN T_TOURNE_LABEL ON TOURNE.LIB_TOURNE = T_TOURNE_LABEL.NOID
               WHERE  THE_FA = @The_FA AND NO_INSEE = @The_Insee AND JOUR = @The_Jour
                               AND ( DATEPART(hh, LE_HEURE) BETWEEN 13 AND 23
                               OR DATEPART(hh, LE_HEURE) BETWEEN 0 AND 6
                               )), '00') AS LIBELLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Code_Tourne_Matin
@The_FA int,
@The_Jour int,
@The_Insee varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
declare @TheCode varchar(250)
    Set @TheCode = '';
    SELECT top 1 @TheCode = T_TOURNE_LABEL.LIBELLE 
            FROM TOURNE
            LEFT JOIN T_TOURNE_LABEL ON TOURNE.LIB_TOURNE = T_TOURNE_LABEL.NOID
            WHERE THE_FA = @The_FA AND 
                NO_INSEE = @The_Insee AND 
                (JOUR = @The_Jour or JOUR = 0 )AND 
                (datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 13 and 23 or datepart(hh, LE_HEURE) between 0 and 6)

    set @TheCode = case
        when len(@TheCode) > 0
        when exists (SELECT @TheCode)
        else '00'

        end
    RETURN @TheCode  
END
```